# Posicionar texto, antes e depois de um hífen alinhado ao centro

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-router

Eu tenho duas informações, um email e um numero ( telefone ), entre os dois coloquei um hífen. Eu quero centralizar o hífen ao meio da tela e colocar o email ao lado esquerdo desse hífen e o numero ao lado direito. Alguem pode me ajudar a como fazer isso, já tentei um monte, e nunca fica alinhado certo. Estou usando o Vue CLI + Vue Router

HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Leads</h1>

    <div class="leads">
      <div v-for="lead in leads" :key="lead.id" class="lead">
        <h2>{{ lead.nome }}</h2>
        <div class="lead-contact">
          <span id="first">{{ lead.email }}</span>
          <b>-</b>
          <span>{{ lead.telefone }}</span>
        </div>
        ...
```

CSS

```
.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26pt;
}

.leads {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  margin-top: 70px;
  align-items: center;
}

.lead {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 700px;

  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.lead h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #9e00ff;
}
```

Para ficar mais claro, eu queria fazer algo desse tipo:
[image: Exemplo feito no Figma]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na classe `.lead-contact` vc coloca `display flex`, e no `spans` que estão dentro coloca `flex: 1` e alinha com `text-align`

```css
.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26pt;
}

.leads {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  margin-top: 70px;
  align-items: center;
}

.lead {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 700px;

  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.lead h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #9e00ff;
}

.lead-contact {
  display: flex;
}
.lead-contact span {
  flex: 1;
}
.lead-contact b {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#first {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Leads</h1>

  <div class="leads">
    <div v-for="lead in leads" :key="lead.id" class="lead">
      <h2>{{ lead.nome }}</h2>
      <div class="lead-contact">
        <span id="first">{{ lead.email }}</span>
        <b>-</b>
        <span>{{ lead.telefone }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="lead-contact">
        <span id="first">123</span>
        <b>-</b>
        <span>123123 123 12 3123 12 213 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="lead-contact">
        <span id="first">abcfsdsdf sdfsdfsd werew werwe</span>
        <b>-</b>
        <span>sfdfsdfs sdfds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ela não fica alinhada no hífen, ele alinha a frase toda.

Comment: @Azus5 acho que agora entendi, da uma olhada na edição que fiz na resposta

Comment: Isso mesmo, você me salvou. Muito obrigado mesmo!!!

Comment: @Azus5 de nada ;)

Comment: Usa o display:flex com um space-between.

Comment: @e200 logicamente vc não testou com space-between né, vc veria que ficaria assim https://prnt.sc/t6e0c3 ... totalmente ERRADO :/